# Strange md-checkbox behavior when initial click happens

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I am getting an unexpected checkbox behavior.

When I initially click on my checkbox I get to the `check()` function of the Facility object, and `this.check` is FALSE, like it should be. My toggle statement `!this.checked` works appropriately and the newState is assigned a value of TRUE. **On the next line, that TRUE value is assigned to `this.checked`, I see the ripple, but no check appears.**

When I subsequently click this checkbox, I again get to the check() function of the Facility object, and despite the checkbox not being checked, this.check   value is TRUE. **My toggle statement works again, and the newState has a value   of FALSE, and this.checked is now FALSE. Strangely enough, after this, the   check appears.**

What is going on?

Parent TreeNode Class

```
export class TreeNode {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    checked: boolean;

    constructor(id: string, name: string) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.checked = false;
    }
}
```

Child Facility Class

```
import { TreeNode } from './tree-node';

export class Facility extends TreeNode {

    constructor(id: string, name: string) {
        super(id, name);
    }

    check() {
        console.log('Facility Check: facility = '+ this.name);
        let newState = !this.checked;
        this.checked = newState;;
    }
 }
```

HTML that iterates over a Facility Array

```
<div *ngFor="let facility of facilities" >
    <md-checkbox [checked]="facility.checked" (click)="facility.check()">  
    {{facility.name}}</md-checkbox>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the (change) event instead of (click), like so:

```
<md-checkbox [checked]="facility.checked" (change)="facility.check()">
```

Otherwise, possibly due to at which point the (click) event calls your "check" method, the contents of your "checked" boolean get messed up.

Additionally, if all you want to do in response to the change is maintain the boolean you can do it with two-way data binding via ngModel as follows:

```
<md-checkbox [(ngModel)]="facility.checked">
```

Comment: Is this a common work around? I will try this out tomorrow.  Thank you for your response.

Comment: I would say that more than a workaround is the way to go with handling the md-checkbox checked state changing. I've edited the answer to add an option using ngModel in case you don't really need to respond to the change event for reasons other than maintaining that boolean.